# what is Sierpiński topology?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Can anyone will help me to get the concept of Sierpiński topology ? how Can we define Sierpiński topology over every set ?

Comment: Do you mean the _Sierpiński_ topology?

Comment: sure ! let me edit it .

Comment: I am learning introduction to topology .

Comment: It’s puzzling why you are asking for a basic definition here. It should be in an introductory book. If not, a Google search will do.

Comment: Thanks for that next time i will be careful about that .

Answer (score 4):

You might mean the [Sierpiński topology](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) instead. This is a topology on the set $\{0,1\}$ with one non-trivial open set, like $\{\emptyset, \{0,1\},\{0\}\}$, so exactly one open singleton and the other one closed. Whether we choose the $0$ to be isolated or $1$, is a matter of convention, as the results will always be homeomorphic.

It’s the minimal example of a space that is $T_0$ but not $T_1$.

So it’s a concrete space, not a class of topologies, as far as I’m aware.